# Function not an explicit function of time notation

Tags: functions, derivatives

So far, in multivariable calculus, I know that given a function $\mathcal{H}\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)$, where $\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_n\end{bmatrix}^\textrm{T}$ is also a function of time, the total derivative is

$$\frac{d\mathcal{H}}{dt} = \frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial t} + \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\mathcal{H}}{\partial x_i}\frac{d x_i}{d t}$$

If $\mathcal{H}$ doesn't depend explicitly on time (that is, no direct relationship), then $\partial\mathcal{H}/\partial t = 0$. Can one say that

$$\mathcal{H} \neq \mathcal{H}\left(t\right)$$ or

$$\mathcal{H} \neq \mathcal{f}\left(t\right)?$$

In mathematical notation, which one is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, writing $\mathcal{H}\neq\mathcal{H}(t)$ makes no sense. Just write $\partial\mathcal{H}/\partial t=0$, which conveys exactly what it says: $\mathcal{H}$ does not change when $t$ changes.

Comment: Yeah I feel that the partial derivative with respect to time $=$ 0 says enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**A note on notation**

In general, when using "$f(x)$" function notation, $f$ is used to denote the *function itself* (e.g. $\lambda x.fx$), whereas $f(x)$ denotes the *value* of $f$ at $x$.

It is technically true that $\mathcal{H}\ne\mathcal{H}(t)$, as "the function $\mathcal{H}$" is *not* equal to "the value of $\mathcal{H}$ at $t$". This is not especially informative, though, since $t$ can just as easily be replaced with a picture of a fish and the statement would remain true.

As stated in obscuran's answer, in order to say that $\mathcal{H}$ is independent of $t$ you would write $\partial\mathcal{H}/\partial t=0$.

Now, if you want to use $\mathcal{H}\ne\mathcal{H}(t)$ as *shorthand* in your own personal notes, that's fine. You don't have to stick to any particular format if you are only writing a note to yourself - just be sure to use proper notation on assignments / in publications.

Comment: Oh ok, I ask because I saw some of my teachers use the $\neq$ notation, which I find misleading.

Comment: @Superman Apparently, this notation is sometimes used in quantum mechanics.